# What are the differences between "tener" and "haber"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, verbos

Both verbs *tener* and *haber* both are translated as *to have*.

What are the rules that distinguish the use of one verb over the other?

Answer (score 4):

**Haber** meaning *to be in possession of* is not really used anymore. However, **haber** meaning *to be obliged to* is equivalent to **tener**:

> Juan tiene que ir al médico.
>
> Juan ha de ir al médico.

Although I would say that the second sentence is more formal.

Other than that, **haber** is mainly used to conjugate other verbs, or meaning *to exist* as explained in [this article by the RAE.](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?val=haber)

Answer (score 4):

You can translate "tener" as to have but I think translating "haber" the same way is far from being the best option. 
"Haber" has quite a few usages and "to have" is the least common (the RAE list it as obsolete http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=5ra5cGATFDXX2hZam4lB)

The main uses of "haber" are as an auxiliary verb for compound verbal constructions and the other is to indicate existence in impersonal sentences (without subject).

- The first usage may be translated as "have" but only auxiliary cases like "See what you have done" "I have had my breakfast", etc.
- The second usage can be translated as "there + to be": There are three dogs in that house --> "Hay tres perros en esa casa"

Answer (score 2):

### Tener

`To have` something.  To possess something, a feeling, etc.

> Tengo dos gatos
>
> Tengo tres dólares en mi mano
>
> Tenemos miedo de tí
>
> Él tiene frío

### Haber

- `To have` existence.
- To be obliged to do something.
- `To have` had done something.

> Hay dos camas en el cuarto
>
> Ya lo he visto
>
> Hay que hacer ejercicios.

It is mainly used in its auxiliary form to create a "perfect" tense.

> Ya comí / I already ate

vs

> Ya he comido / I have already eaten

Answer (score 0):

"Haber" and "tener" have very different meanings and can almost never be used interchangeably. Haber can mean there is/are or can be used to form the perfect tense.

e.g: ***Hay** muchas personas aquí* = There are many people here. (haber in the sense of 'there is'.
*Ya **has** comido?* = have you eaten? (haber in the perfect tense)

Tener generally means to have but can also be often translated as 'to be' in [certain expressions](https://www.clozemaster.com/blog/spanish-tener-expressions/http://).

e.g:*tengo dos perros*=I have two dogs.
*tienes un cigarrillo?*=Do you have a cigarette?

*tengo hambre*=I am hungry.
*Él tiene seis años*=He is six years old

In short, if you are wanting to say 'to have' in the traditional sense of the verb, use 'tener'. If you want to say 'to have' to express the perfect tense, use 'haber'.

This blog post goes into more detail:
Haber vs tener: https://www.clozemaster.com/blog/spanish-haber-vs-tener/

Clozemaster is a language learning game. Its blog has a lot of useful posts on Spanish grammar. Hope this could be of help.

Comment: If the link goes dead this is not going to be very helpful. Could you edit your answer to include more detail from the blog you link to?

Comment: Hi there, I have edited my answer to include more information and gave some more info about the blog as well. Hope that is sufficient.